# Why we use -'0' beside charAt(i)?

Tags: java, string

I read Hello Android book and i dont understand a piece of code this function.

Why we use -'0' beside charAt(i)??

```
static protected int[] fromPuzzleString(String string) {
    int[] puz = new int[string.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < puz.length; i++) {
        puz[i] = string.charAt(i) - '0' ;
    }
    return puz; 
 }
```

Thanks you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Because `string.charAt(i)` returns `char`. But `puz` is `int[]`.

So `string.charAt(i) - '0'`converts it to an integer.

Comment: Note that this is terrible code. It's slightly arcane, only works with ASCII and is much harder to parse mentally. Much better to use `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` wants a `String`, not a `char`.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi That won't work. `Integer.parseInt()` receives a `String`, but `string.charAt(i)` returns a `char`.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi It's true it's only ASCII, but bear in mind the code itself is a *very* common pattern, decades old; we've been using it since ASCII and chars. For us old people, it reads pretty naturally.

Comment: @oscar @petar So use `Integer.parseInt()` with one of the substring methods. It's not rocket science. @Dave it reads naturally to me too. It's still an awful hack, especially in a "modern" language like Java.

Comment: @petar I've upvoted your answer. It's not your fault the code in question was a poor but of coding. ;)

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is read a char, one at a time, convert it to an int and store it in your array.

The ASCII code for 0 is 48. So what you're actually trying to do is *subtract* this value from the ASCII value of the *char* at that particular location and then store the numeric result in the corresponding index.

You can verify it for yourself, if you try to print it out in your loop, something like:

```
System.out.println((int)string.charAt(i));
System.out.println((int)'0');
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Thanks! Sometime I think more than I should :(

Answer (score 2):

You're better off using [`Character.isDigit(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) and [`Character.getNumericValue(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) to test and convert a char into an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

The string is a number.This code will convert the string into an integer array.
`string.charAt(i)` will return a character and `string.charAt(i)- '0'` will return the actual integer value.
For e.g. string="12345",this method will return an integer array [1,2,3,4,5].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose of this specific operation, but in Java (and in many programming languages) characters (`char`) are represented as an integer value (only smaller 2 bytes in java). You can explicitly cast characters to integer like this:

```
int x = (int) 'a';
```

I think this code does something similar. The `String.charAt()` function returns a `char`, and if you treat it like an int, it has a value like 120 (only an example). '0' (as a `char`) has also a value. If you substract them, you get an integer value.